# Как изменить размер памяти memcached?

Tags: memcached, ubuntu

По умолчанию memcached использует до 64 Мб памяти. Можно из командной строки задать размер опцией -m:

```
memcached -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1 -m 128 -d
```

Но после перезагрузки он вернется в 64 Мб. Вопрос, как изменить (увеличить) это размер так, чтобы при перезагрузке системы он сохранялся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему вы не ставите это значение при загрузке?

А еще можно поправить Init Script:

> If you have installed memcached from
> your OS's package management system,
> odds are it already comes with an init
> script. They come with alternative
> methods to configure what startup
> options memcached receives. Such as
> via a /etc/sysconfig/memcached file.
> Make sure you check these before you
> run off editing init scripts or
> writing your own.
>
> If you're building memcached yourself,
> the 'scripts/' directory in the source
> tarball contains several examples of
> init scripts.

Comment: Ок. Поискал в ubuntu - скрипт установок лежит в /etc/memcached.conf. Если там прописать -m 128, то после перезагрузки memcached использует 128 Мб.

Comment: Логично:)